# Acumatica - PXDBScalar with calculation

Tags: .net, acumatica

I'm looking to write add a calculated field for the ARTran table, which converts the Qty to a specified universal UOM.

Normally I'd use one of the calculation attributes but I'm unsure how to add operands to the Search<> query. Ideally the logic would be

```
Search2<Mult<ARTran.baseQty, INUnit.unitRate>, 
     InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>>,
     InnerJoin<INUnit, On<INUnit.fromUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.baseUnit>, And<INUnit.toUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.purchaseUnit>>>>>,
```

Failing that, I've been trying to write an attribute which will subscribe a RowSelected event to calculate the value. This works on the Invoices screen correctly, however when the DAC is used in a GI the row data is empty when the RowSelected event is called.

Any help with either solution would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is that each record selection method has it's own limitations.

You could use `PXFormula` for the `Mult` clause but not for the `Join` clauses.

You could use `PXDBScalar` for the `Join` clauses but not for the `Mult` clause.

This inconsistency is vexing but you could use 2 custom fields to get around the  limitation by using both `PXFormula` and `PXDBScalar`:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARTranExt : PXCacheExtension<ARTran>
    {
        #region UsrUniversalUOM 
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Mult<ARTran.baseQty, usrUnitRate>))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Universal UOM")]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrUniversalUOM { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrUniversalUOM : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrUnitRate
        [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<INUnit.unitRate,
                           InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>>>,
                           Where<INUnit.inventoryID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>,
                           And<INUnit.fromUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.baseUnit>,
                           And<INUnit.toUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.purchaseUnit>>>>>))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unit Rate")]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrUnitRate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrUnitRate : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

If you need `Unit Rate` to be invisible in the grid you can set it's `Visibility` property to invisible.

[image]